# Visualize taps/gestures for flutter-test (or flutter-driver)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

When using `flutter_driver` / `flutter_test`, we simulate user behavior by doing things like `await tap()`. However, I want to *see where is tapped on the screen of emulator*. Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: from developer options in your device you can turn on `show taps` it is usually in `input` section of developer options on Android Q

Comment: @dev-aentgs it seems that flutter driver uses some internal mechanism (e.g. hit testing) instead of simulating a "real user" click. thus imho this may not work?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do that / what is it that you want to achieve. I can answer with a way to do what you are asking, but it might not be what you are looking for.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot This can be used in many situations. For example, by doing this, we can easily see what the tester is tapping and easier to debug.

Comment: @ch271828n So the only thing you care about are some indicators visible on tap? How detailed of an answer do you need? Can you work with something that shows you all the necessary concepts?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Any idea is acceptable (I am not new to Flutter :) ). Not only about indicators visible on tap, but also other things, such as recording the location tapped, etc. And mightychris who gives the bounty may have other things that he wants. If there is no better answer I will give the bounty to you :)

Comment: the visuals were all I wanted. I've got a recipe for recording flutter_driver tests in GitHub actions to video and uploading them as artifacts. This would let me see when tests fail because clicks miss

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My idea for this (since Flutter Driver and widget tests do not use real taps) is to record the taps on a Flutter-level, i.e. using Flutter hit testing.

I will present you with a **widget** that you can wrap your app in to **visualize** and **capture** *all* taps. I wrote [a complete widget for this](https://gist.github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/cd42b60cb33c9962b19f629ec638d4de).

### Demonstration

Here is the result when wrapping the widget around the default template demo app:

[image]

### Implementation

What we want to do is simple: **react** to **all** tap events in the size of our widget (the whole app is our child).
However, it comes with a little challenge: `GestureDetector` e.g. will not *let taps through* after reacting to them. So if we were to use a [`TapGestureRecognizer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/TapGestureRecognizer-class.html), we could either not react to taps that hit buttons in our app **or** we would not be able to hit the buttons (would only see our indication).

Therefore, we need to use our **own render object** to do the job. This is not a hard task when you a familiar with - [`RenderProxyBox`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderProxyBox-class.html) is just the abstraction we need :)

#### Catching hit events

By overriding [`hitTest`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderBox/hitTest.html), we can make sure that we always record hits:

```dart
@override
bool hitTest(BoxHitTestResult result, {required Offset position}) {
  if (!size.contains(position)) return false;
  // We always want to add a hit test entry for ourselves as we want to react
  // to each and every hit event.
  result.add(BoxHitTestEntry(this, position));
  return hitTestChildren(result, position: position);
}
```

Now, we can use [`handleEvent`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderBox/handleEvent.html) to both record the hit events and also visualize them:

```dart
@override
void handleEvent(PointerEvent event, covariant HitTestEntry entry) {
  // We do not want to interfere in the gesture arena, which is why we are not
  // using regular tap recognizers. Instead, we handle it ourselves and always
  // react to the hit events (ignoring the gesture arena).
  if (event is PointerDownEvent) {
    // Record the global position.
    recordTap(event.position);

    // Visualize local position.
    visualizeTap(event.localPosition);
  }
}
```

#### Visualizing

I will spare you the details (full code at the end): I decided to create an [`AnimationController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html) for each recorded hit and store that along with the local position.

Since we are using a `RenderProxyBox`, we can just call `markNeedsPaint` when the animation controller fires and then paint a circle for all recorded taps:

```dart
@override
void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
  context.paintChild(child!, offset);

  final canvas = context.canvas;
  for (final tap in _recordedTaps) {
    drawTap(canvas, tap);
  }
}
```

### Code

Of course, I glanced over most parts of the implementation because you can just read through them :)
The code should be straight-forward since I outlined the concepts I used.

You can find ***[the full source code here](https://gist.github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/cd42b60cb33c9962b19f629ec638d4de)***.

#### Usage

The usage is straight-forward:

```dart
TapRecorder(
  child: YourApp(),
)
```

Even in my example implementation, you can configure the tap circle color, size, duration, etc.:

```dart
/// These are the parameters for the visualization of the recorded taps.
const _tapRadius = 15.0,
    _tapDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 420),
    _tapColor = Colors.white,
    _shadowColor = Colors.black,
    _shadowElevation = 2.0;
```

You could make them widget parameters if you wanted to.

#### Testing

I hope that the visualization part lives up to your expectations.

If you want to go beyond that, I made sure that the taps are stored globally:

```dart
/// List of the taps recorded by [TapRecorder].
///
/// This is only a make-shift solution of course. This will only be viable
/// when using a single [TapRecorder] because it is saved as a top-level
/// variable.
@visibleForTesting
final recordedTaps = <Offset>[];
```

You can simply access the list in tests to check the recorded taps :)

## The end

I had a lot of fun implementing this and I hope it met your expectations.
The implementation is just a quick make-shift one, however, I hope it can provide you with all the concepts needed to take this idea to a good level :)

Comment: Looks great! Thanks! I can get the idea of this implementation :)

Comment: well done! bounty awarded! I wonder how hard it would be to graft this in via a flutter driver instrumentation wrapper

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer again! Today need to not only show the tap events, but show everything (including drag, scroll, etc), so I modify your solution and it works well (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my modification to @creativecreatorormaybenot.

In my recent case, I need to not only show the *tap* events, but show *everything* (including drag, scroll, etc). So I modify it as follows, and it works well :)

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

/// These are the parameters for the visualization of the recorded taps.
final _kTapRadius = 15.0, _kTapColor = Colors.grey[300]!, _kShadowColor = Colors.black, _kShadowElevation = 3.0;
const _kRemainAfterPointerUp = Duration(milliseconds: 100);

/// NOTE: refer to this answer for why use hitTest/handleEvent/etc https://stackoverflow.com/a/65067655
///
/// Widget that visualizes gestures.
///
/// It does not matter to this widget whether the child accepts the hit events.
/// Everything hitting the rect of the child will be recorded.
class GestureVisualizer extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  const GestureVisualizer({Key? key, required Widget child}) : super(child: child);

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return _RenderGestureVisualizer();
  }
}

class _RenderGestureVisualizer extends RenderProxyBox {
  /// key: pointer id, value: the info
  final _recordedPointerInfoMap = <int, _RecordedPointerInfo>{};

  @override
  void detach() {
    _recordedPointerInfoMap.clear();
    super.detach();
  }

  @override
  bool hitTest(BoxHitTestResult result, {required Offset position}) {
    if (!size.contains(position)) return false;
    // We always want to add a hit test entry for ourselves as we want to react
    // to each and every hit event.
    result.add(BoxHitTestEntry(this, position));
    return hitTestChildren(result, position: position);
  }

  @override
  void handleEvent(PointerEvent event, covariant HitTestEntry entry) {
    // We do not want to interfere in the gesture arena, which is why we are not
    // using regular tap recognizers. Instead, we handle it ourselves and always
    // react to the hit events (ignoring the gesture arena).

    // by experiment, sometimes we see PointerHoverEvent with pointer=0 strangely...
    if (event.pointer == 0) {
      return;
    }

    if (event is PointerUpEvent || event is PointerCancelEvent) {
      Future.delayed(_kRemainAfterPointerUp, () {
        _recordedPointerInfoMap.remove(event.pointer);
        markNeedsPaint();
      });
    } else {
      _recordedPointerInfoMap[event.pointer] = _RecordedPointerInfo(event.localPosition);
      markNeedsPaint();
    }
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    context.paintChild(child!, offset);

    final canvas = context.canvas;
    for (final info in _recordedPointerInfoMap.values) {
      final path = Path()..addOval(Rect.fromCircle(center: info.localPosition, radius: _kTapRadius));

      canvas.drawShadow(path, _kShadowColor, _kShadowElevation, true);
      canvas.drawPath(path, Paint()..color = _kTapColor);
    }
  }
}

class _RecordedPointerInfo {
  _RecordedPointerInfo(this.localPosition);

  final Offset localPosition;
}
```